# Xcode 7 How to Configure a Git Network Repository

Tags: xcode, git

I am about to start developing an application in Xcode 7 and will be working on the code from different locations on different Macs. I want to configure a Git repository on my fileserver (Snow Leopard Server) where my code will reside, and will be regularly backed up from, so that I can 'check out' code to whichever Mac I am working on, work with it and 'check in' afterwards. Is this possible?

I am used to working in IntelliJ IDEA where I simply create a bare repository on my fileserver, create my new IntelliJ project on my local Mac and then 'push' my local code to my network repository when needed.

Many thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your own git server installed locally but its much better to use a service like bitbucket (private repo) or any other free git hosting service.

If you still decide to have it locally on your mac here are the instruction on ow to do it.
http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-processes/how-to-set-up-a-secure-git-server-at-home-osx/

Comment: Thanks CodeWizard. I created a bare repository on our fileserver and was able to set this as my remote.

Comment: Coo, Please be kind enough to accept and vote for the answer.